# display div tag in ng-click

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I need to display the div tag which is in another page 'permenent.html' in my header.html page. now shows as alert message in Permenent_model.html. I want to display as div tag ie merge div tag with another page. 
[image]
[image]

```
          Permenent_model.html
           <div ng-controller="PermenentModalController">
            <h4> This is permenent modal page </h4>
            <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="permenentmodal()"> Show permenent modal </a>
         </div>

         Controller
          comApp.controller("PermenentModalController",              function($scope,msgmodal,$rootScope,$window,$location) {

    //go to permenent modal
     $scope.permenentmodal = function(){

       msgmodal.permenentModal(''); //now shows as model here 

     }
    });
   permenent.html
   <div class="sample">
   hello 
   </div>
```

Comment: Format your code. Then just use ngInclude/ngShow/ngIf.

Comment: can you say how to use it plz

Comment: <div ng-if="someCondition"><a href="/link-to-tab">tab</a></div> would be the quickest way to achieve this... now if these are two separate pages you either change the someCondition on the $rootScope, or have a base controller or use some sort of event such as $emit and in the header controller catch that event